# How to change the name of the entry point file in Flask?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

I'm relatively inexperienced Python user and completely new to Flask, so I am sure this is dumb, but...

I had a file that acted as an entry point for Flask, named `some_silly_name.py` which contains the line `app = Flask(__name__)`. The server was running fine, until I decided that that name was silly, so I renamed the file to `a_much_better_name.py`. Now on `flask run` I get the error `Error: Could not import "some_silly_name"`.

What do I need to do to change the name of this file and still have Flask run?

Comment: Are you defining a environment variable in .flaskenv? Did you change that to `a_much_better_name.py`?

Comment: @badri I'm not using a .flaskenv file, no.

Comment: What is the full traceback?

Comment: @Lasf can you post your tree structure of the project?

Comment: @roganjosh no traceback, it literally just says `Error: Could not import "some_silly_name"`

Comment: @badri it's just a single file sitting in the project root! Other than the venv that's it.

Comment: Are you on Windows or Linux? Do `set FLASK_APP=a_much_better_name.py` (or `export` instead of `set` for Linux). I suspect you forgot to change this environment variable

Comment: @roganjosh that did it. Thanks mate.

Comment: Try export FLASK_APP=a_much_better_name.py

Comment: Looks like you got it @Lasf

Comment: @badri Cheers, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did actually set an environment variable with:

`export FLASK_APP=some_silly_name.py`

(Or with `set` instead of `export` on Windows). Even if you change your entry point file name and correct all references to the original file within the app, you'll need to re-set this variable to point to the new entry point.

Answer (score 0):

Check your import statement... to be sure that you have also changed the file name from the sily_name to the better_name

Your code will help to easily point you in the right direction.